# How would you get the last 10 keys redis?

Tags: database, web-applications, nosql, redis, key

Let's say I have a database with 1,000,000 keys. Is there a way to know the last 10 keys from that database?

Comment: nope, you have to implement it yourself

Comment: And how would you go about doing this?

Comment: you can store keys in a list or in a sorted set

Comment: I see. So I would need make a list that stores all the available keys?

Comment: well depending on the space you want to invest with this.I would keep the size of this list to a fixed length

Comment: Would there be a way to even get the last key in the database?

Comment: @Sivapriyan can you tell us more about what you need the last 10 *keys* in particular for? Maybe we can recommend a workaround. As Tommaso Barbugli said, to do what you want, you'd need to use a secondary structure like a list or a sorted set (slower) to get at the last n keys.

Comment: what is "last" in "the last 10 keys"?

Answer (score 7):

You will need to maintain it as another list using the following commands.

```
Add new key to the front of the list  
LPUSH last10keys key

Retain only the last 10
LTRIM last10keys 0 9

Get the last keys - will return 10 or less
LRANGE mylist 0 9
```

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround if I don't want to change anything in the cache, I tail the AOF file to see what's the latest change there.

> tail -f /var/lib/redis/appendonly.aof

From there, you can see the key, value and command used.

Comment: This requires appendonly to be set to yes in the config file. That is not the default.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pipeline to get last inserted keys or specific keys from the Redis Database

Here is my code example :

```
r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port= 6379, db =0)
# Day1 hash for 24 hours 
# Key , Field , Value
r.hset("31/8/21", "12am", "/home/user/video1.mp4")
r.hset("31/8/21", "1am", "/home/user/video2.mp4")
r.hset("31/8/21", "2am", "/home/user/video3.mp4")
r.hset("31/8/21", "3am", "/home/user/video4.mp4")
r.hset("31/8/21", "4am", "/home/user/video5.mp4")
.
.
#Created sorted set for all the date hashes into single "date" key
r.sadd("date", "25/8/21")
r.sadd("date", "26/8/21")
r.sadd("date", "27/8/21")
r.sadd("date", "28/8/21")
r.sadd("date", "29/8/21")
r.sadd("date", "30/8/21")
r.sadd("date", "31/8/21")
r.save

@app.get("/lastweek")
def sortweek():
        lastweeklist = r.sort("date", 27, -1, alpha=True) #sorted set key > date
        pipe = r.pipeline()
        for keys in lastweeklist:
                pipe.hgetall(keys) #hvals
        week1 = []
        for week in pipe.execute():
                week1.append(week)
        return week1
```

Answer (score 0):

Some commands has  `[LIMIT offset count]` wich you can fill and get limited number of items.

like `zrevrangebyscore key +inf 0 LIMIT 0 20` which gives you top 20 items of a sorted set.